# ubuntu software update problem in 14.04

Tags: updates

when i click ok to software update it shows 'This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources' please help me how to get out from this problem

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command,

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

Then use this command to install,

sudo apt-get upgrade